# How to create ongoing log of database actions on Custom Object records?

Tags: logging, dml-operations

Context: A specific kind of sObject which is the detail in a master-detail relationship is getting mysteriously deleted across a number of different Master records.

I have been trying to narrow the variables down, but it would be great if I could assign a continuous log (beyond just a 24 hour allotment) that could show me all DML statements run against all records, and the users that triggered it.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: can you inspect the recycle bin? that would identify user

Comment: It would be fairly simple to write an after delete trigger if you don't find anything out of the box.

Comment: @cropredy I did do that and couldn't find any relevant deleted records that match the timeline, which makes me suspect a scheduled upsert we're performing on one of the master records is somehow deleting the programs and wiping the media placements without a trace

Comment: Delete of master records would cascade delete the details and there would be no trace of their deletion.  Adrian's suggestion would work if somewhere there is an explicit DML delete of the detail or you extended the trigger to include deletes of the master.

Comment: @cropredy for sure! any recommended pointers on trigger a log creation upon DML actions being called on specific sObjects?

Comment: GPP -- you're going to need to have each sobject-of-interest's `after delete` trigger do DML to some custom `Log__c` object using the values in `Trigger.old`

Comment: @cropredy thanks! And just to be clear-- this would involve writing 'actual' Apex triggers I would push into prod from Sandbox, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct; there is no way to 'subscribe' to DML events so each sobject you care about tracking will need to do the logging explicitly - of course, do the logging through a utility class/method that is simply passed `trigger.old`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Custom object for logging**

`DML_Log__c`  with fields:

- `SObjectType__c`  (type = Text)
- `Name__c` (type = Text)
- `ID__c` (type = text)
- `RecordTypeId__c` (type = Text)

**Utility method**

```
public static void logDmlDelete(Sobject[] sObjList) {
    DML_Log__c[] logInsList = new List<DML_Log__c>();
    for (Sobject sobj : sobjList)
       logInsList.add(new DML_Log__c(
                       sobjectType__c = sobj.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName(),               
                       name__c = (String) sobj.get('name'),
                       id__c = (String) sobj.get('ID'),
                       recordtypeId__c = sobj.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos().size() <= 1  // master recordtype will exist in describe even if no others 
                                        ? null
                                        : (String) sobj.get('recordtypeId') 
                                 ));

    insert logInsList; 
}
```

**Trigger on Foo__c**

```
trigger fooDelete on foo__c on (after delete) {
  ... other stuff
  Util.logDmlDelete(Trigger.old);
}
```

*Notes:*

1. Assumes that the sobject has a Name field
2. Logs only the name field and sobject type; implicitly created by user = user doing the deletes

Comment: wow, this is super baller, thanks! What does Foo__c represent in this case? The custom object being logged?

Comment: @GPP -- sorry, typo in the trigger definition; yes - `Foo__c` is the object being logged; you'd need similar ones for each sobject you are trying to log

Comment: gotcha, thanks. And SObject_Type__c refers to the 'type' of SObject (e.g. CustomObj1 vs Custom Obj2, or is this only firing for a specific Object regardless?

Comment: @GPP Yes - the name of the sobject - so the log can record dml events on many sobjects using a single field

Comment: thanks! And btw it looks like I had to wrap the method you gave in your answer in a class notation: " public class dmlDeleteLog { //cropredy's baller code method ... }
Does that sound/look right to you?

Comment: Also, the 'Util in Util.logDmlDeleted' variable isn't being recognized...any idea why that might be?

Comment: @GPP put the method inside a class called Util - that was my intent; I assumed you already had a Util-type class in your system

Comment: thanks again for all your help! Final question(s): I would like to pass in the SObject's Id and Record Type. Here's the code I tried for Ids (unsuccessful):
SObject_Id__c = (String) sobj.get('Id')
Also, if I have an SObject that does not have Record Types (some custom objects) do I need to write an If statement that accommodates for null Record Type strings?

Comment: @copyredy -- Actually, my Id logging code passed in a value, but it's not the Id for that record. (I copied before deleting).
 So question still stands, along with how to retrieve the RecordType, and if I need to create an IF statement for Null/Non existent Record Type fields...

Comment: @GPP - made enhancements to handle `recordTypeId`

Comment: cropredy you're my hero. However, I am trying to get the actual Name of the record type for the sObject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38942/discussion-between-cropredy-and-gpp).